# In firebase realtime databse for web app, how do I move from one level to another?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I have my firebase realtime database connected to my web app. Now suppose as in the picture, I am currently at 'a' using ref and now I want to get the value of 'd1'. How do I do that?

[image: my database looks something like this]

Comment: You may have a look at the following help page: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As detailed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=0#read_data_once), you can use one of the two following approaches:

```
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('a/b/c/c1/d1')
    .once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
```

or

```
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('a')
    .once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      const aObject = snapshot.val();
      console.log(aObject.b.c.c1.d1);
    });
```

Note that in the second case you will get the entire JSON tree under `a`, since queries with the Realtime Database [are not shallow](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/firestore-for-rtdb#best_practices_in_action).